# react final form prevent formatted value from storing in form state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

I have an input component where when user enters anything it formats it in a particular way.But the formatted part I want just for the sake of displaying and not storing in the form state.

[Here is an example of it](https://codesandbox.io/s/3rp260ly51)

In the price field after entering the value, on blur of it, the value is formatted with comma(,) like so `$1,212,121.00`, but this value I want it for display purpose only and not in state.In state it should be stored as `1212121` or `1212121.00` anything is fine.Tried using [parse](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#parse-value-any-name-string--any--null) as mentioned in docs but since `formatOnBlur` is being used so `format` runs after `parse`.How shall I do it?

Comment: Store value of input state as it is, and on value call a function that returns formatted text.

Comment: value is only for checkbox and radio buttons https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#value-any

Comment: You have a stateless component anyway - nothing's in the state. Change it to a class component if you want to use state, or use the Hooks API with useState.

Comment: How will it help and I need the data to be stored in form state not in component state @markmoxx